# Replace all instances of '=' with '==' in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

I have a c# string expression where i'd like to replace all instances of `'='` with `'=='`

e.g

```
1 = 1
```

should be

```
1 == 1
```

However, I can't just do a `replace('=','==')` because `'1 == 1'` would become `'1 ==== 1'`

Is there a Regex or something I could use instead?

Comment: Regex is best answer, because it covers "1=1" but for "1 = 1" situations you can often use the spacing: replace("= ","==")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Regex which will match only a single equals sign and call Replace on that Regex.

```
new Regex("={1,}").Replace("=", "==")
```

Returns `==`

```
new Regex("={1,}").Replace("==", "==")
```

Returns `==`